# How to obtain drawableLeftCompat clickEvent in databinding xml

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, android-databinding, androidx

I'm new to databinding and below my xml code and I know how to handle it java or kotlin, but trying to achieve through xml.

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_likes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dime_30"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dimen_5"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/dimen_5"
                android:text="@{``+obj.likeCount}"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
                android:onClick="@{() -> onItemClick.onLikeClicked()}"
                app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/iv_vector_heart_likes" />
```

Comment: `drawableLeftCompat` has no click event.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Thanks for your reply. can't we achieve touch event or any? from databinding